# Can't pull from one bare git repo to another

Tags: git

Here's my setup:

I've got one a 'master' git repository with a hosted service. All code must end up on here. Call this 'master'.

Because of permissions (wanting to limit the number of SSH keys used for the hosted service), and because I initially started coding pointing to another repo, I've got a bare repository on a VPS. Call this 'VPS'.

I work locally on development, push to VPS, log into VPS periodically and push to master.

The problem I've got is that I deployed my web site by cloning from master. I made some changes and pushed them back to master. So now I need to execute `git pull` on VPS so it'll get the latest code from master. Unfortunately when I try this, git tells me I can't do this with a bare repository. To make things more complicated I didn't realise this, so I've pushed some new code from development to VPS, so VPS is missing some commits part way through the log (i.e. not the most recent commits made across all the code).

How can I fix this, and what would be a good way of setting things up so I can push and pull from VPS?

Thanks

-- edit --

OK, so I need to be able to merge the last 3 commits from VPS into a new clone of master. How can I do this, and how should I configure the repositories in git?

Comment: Pull from both master and VPS in the deployed website repo, and merge stuff there, then push to master / VPS.

Comment: @Artefact2 - the deployed site only has access to master, not VPS unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to do a merge (or cherrypick, which could involve merge), you need to do it on a repository that is not bare.

You could do it on your local development machine. Make both master and VPS remotes, fetch from both, and merge them both into you local development master branch. Then push this branch to VPS, then push it from VPS to master. Both those pushes should be fast-forward and work (provided no one has pushed any changes to VPS or master in the mean time, in that case merge again).

Another alternative is to convert VPS from bare to normal and do the merge there. You can do this by recreating VPS (clone from master without the --bare switch). If you recreate it in the same place, the remote settings for local development will still point to it.

Comment: I kind of did it the second way, but it wouldn't quite work so I ended up using git diff and patch in the end. Not ideal since I've lost some metadata, but not the end of the world. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`git pull` is the equivalent of `git fetch` + `git merge`.

Merging obviously requires a working copy (in order to be able to resolve conflicts, if any).

Since you don't actually want to merge anything when moving stuff between two bare repositories (merging should be done in your own clone's working copy), and you just want to get the new value of a branch, you should just invoke `git fetch` directly.

Comment: Hmm... The `git fetch` worked on VPS, but I need to merge the changes that I pushed directly to master somehow since it didn't pull those in because I've since committed to VPS. I've cloned master somewhere else. Can I cherry-pick the last 3 commits to VPS to this new repo? That's what I need to do...

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your problem. You have access to both VPS and master. You can push and pull from/to both. You can just pull from both, merge those changes and then push up the result to both.

Comment: I was not aware of being able to pull/push from both. So I did clone from proxy.git bare-repo, cd into non-bare clone, pull from master.git bare-repo (the pull also did the merge), then push to proxy.git. Finally I cd'd into proxy.git and did a push to master.git. <now the two bare repos are in sync>. Then I tested by cloning from both master.git and proxy.git. Did a directory compare on the content using `kompare` and the contents were identical. --> sounds like setting two remotes would be much easier?